# Removing \n \\n and other unwanted characters from a json unicode dictionary with python

Tags: json, python-2.7, dictionary, unicode, strip

I've tried a couple of different solutions to fix my problem with some "funny" newlines within my json dictionary and none of them works, so I thought I might make a post. The dictionary is achieved by scraping a website.

I have a json dictionary:

```
my_dict = {
    u"Danish title": u"Avanceret", 
    u"Course type": u"MScTechnol",
    u"Type of":  u"assessmen",
    u"Date": u"\nof exami",
    u"Evaluation": u"7 step sca",
    u"Learning objectives": u"\nA studen",
    u"Participants restrictions": u"Minimum 10",
    u"Aid": u"No Aid",
    u"Duration of Course": u"13 weeks",
    u"name": u"Advanced u",
    u"Department": u"31\n",
    u"Mandatory Prerequisites": u"31545",
    u"General course objectives": u"\nThe cour",
    u"Responsible": u"\nMartin C",
    u"Location": u"Campus Lyn",
    u"Scope and form": u"Lectures, ",
    u"Point( ECTS )": u"10",
    u"Language": u"English",
    u"number": u"31548",
    u"Content": u"\nThe cour",
    u"Schedule": u"F4 (Tues 1"
}
```

I have stripped the value content to `[:10]` to reduce clutter, but some of the values have a length of 300 characters. It might not be portrayed well here, but some of values have a lot of newline characters in them and I've tried a lot of different solutions to remove them, such as `str.strip` and `str.replace` but without success because my 'values' are **unicode**. And by values I mean `key, value in my_dict.items()`.

How do I remove all the newlines appearing in my dictionary? (With the values in focus as some of the newlines are trailing, some are leading and others are in the middle of the content: e.i `\nI have a\ngood\n idea\n`).

## EDIT

I am using **Python v. 2.7.11** and the following piece of code doesn't produce what I need. I want all the newlines to be changed to a single whitespace character.

```
for key, value in test.items():
    value = str(value[:10]).replace("\n", " ")
    print key, value
```

Comment: Please give an example where 'str.replace' doesn't work. You may edit the question and add them.

Comment: Do you want to remove the newlines or do you want to replace them with a single space? You need to mention which Python version you're using (preferably with a tag), since Unicode handling is quite different in Python 2 vs Python 3. You may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to remove all `\n` or any junk character apart from numbers or letters then use regex

```
for key in my_dict.keys():
    my_dict[key] = mydict[key].replace('\\n', '')
    my_dict[key] = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9 ]+', '', my_dict[key])
print my_dict
```

If you wish to keep anything apart from those then add it on to the character class inside the regex

Comment: Sadly this removes all the whitespace characters. Adding to that none the line breaks are not removed either, only the forward slash as that is not included in the regex.

Comment: now it should run fine, check for the space included in the character class

Comment: Yeah. It runs good now and the text is _almost_ as needed except for one thing. The letter "n" from the "\n" is still left in the text.

Comment: check your output, It removes all special characters. there's nothing left other than the proper output

Comment: It works in some of the cases. But not all. "AssesmentOral\nExamination" turns into "AssesmentOralnExamination" and "internal\nexaminer" becomes "internalnexaminer" and "\nTo gain..." turns into "nTo gain..." It seems as it doesn't work when the \n is in the middle of two words.

Comment: @Zeliax dude check your output, it runs fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110835/discussion-between-zeliax-and-sameera-sy).

Answer (score 0):

for remove '\n' try this ....

for key, value in my_dict.items():
       my_dict[key] = ''.join(value.split('\n'))

Answer (score 0):

you need to put the updated value back to your dictionary ( similar to "by value vs. by reference" situation ;) ) ...

to remove the "/n" this one liner may be more "pythonic" :

```
new_test ={ k:v.replace("\n", "") for k,v in test.iteritems()}
```

to do what you try to do in your loop try something like:

```
new_test ={ k:str(value[:10]).replace("\n", " ") for k,v in test.iteritems()}
```

In your code, value takes the new value, but you never write it back...
So for example, this would work (but be slower, also you would be changing the values inside the loop, which should not cause problems, but the interpreter might not like...):

```
for key, value in test.items():
    value = str(value[:10]).replace("\n", " ")
    #now put it back to the dictionary...
    test[key]=value
    print key, value
```